# Is there a name for the distinct lines in a plot of primes: $p_n/p_{n-1}$ vs $n$

Tags: prime-numbers

If you plot the ratios of consecutive primes against the number of preceding primes there is a whole bunch of distinct lines.

Do they have a name? Do the individual lines have a formula?

Here's a plot of $p_n/p_{n-1}$ against $n$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.
[image: p_n/p_{n-1}]

Comment: Maybe you can have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367197/prime-numbers-what-explains-this-pattern) for a clue...

Comment: Matthew's deleted answer is almost good : you are plotting $(n+1,1+\frac{g(n)}{p_n})\approx (n+1,1+\frac{g(n)}{n \log n})$ where $g(n)= p_{n+1}-p_n$ is an integer and $p_n \sim n \log n$ is the prime number theorem. The distinct curves are the different values of $g(n)$.

Comment: @reuns Yeah, I plotted functions of that form, they're close, but what was odd is that they were out by a really consistent amount. I added in a term of $\log\log n - 1$ and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: $\log \log n-1$ where ?

Comment: @reuns I used the approximation $p_n = n (\log n + \log\log n - 1)$